# How to ''jail'' a java program via chroot? (Fedora 23)

Tags: fedora, chroot

I recently created a MineCraft server in **Fedora 23**, and faced with problem "What if bad guys want to find really important files in my computer? I have to protect my files!"

My jar is in `/home/` directory. But I afraid if i move it to other directory bad guys will have access to my files because all programs have access to all directories in my user at the beginning.

I think, that I must use `chroot`. But the main problem is: I DON'T KNOW HOW.

Comment: My personal recommendation is to use docker. There are plenty of minecraft images available, with instructions on how to use them. If you have to ask the question about how to use chroot, docker will be much easier to work with, and more secure.

Comment: @Patrick by default docker runs as root and offers no security whatsoever. Do not use docker for security.

Comment: @LtWorf I think you're misunderstanding how docker works. Yes inside a container the default user is root, but that's trivial to change. And also even when running as root, it's still pretty secure. You have to escape the container to be able to do any damage to the host system.

Comment: @Patrick by default in docker you run as root AND that root user maps to the root user on the system. Which means it can escape if the capabilities and such aren't set correctly. Easier to just use user namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Patrick's suggestion of `docker` is good.  Any other virtualisation method would work well too (e.g. `VirtualBox` or `kvm`).

Another option is to create another user (e.g. `minecraft`) on your system just for running minecraft server.  Give it it's own group (e.g. `minecraft`) and make sure all minecraft files have RW access for group, then add your own user to the `minecraft` group so your user has full read + write access to minecraft files.

You can also set up permissions on all minecraft files and directories so that the minecraft user doesn't have write access to most of its own files (only to the files that minecraft absolutely must be able to write).  This would require that the minecraft user **NOT** be a member of the minecraft group (maybe have `nobody` or `nogroup` as its primary gid).

Anyone who compromises the minecraft server will have access only to minecraft-owned files, and those that are read or write by everyone. - make sure your files don't have such lax permissions.

Comment: Setting the user's shell to a restricted shell only affects what happens if the credentials to the minecraft account are compromised, not if a process running as minecraft is compromised. If the attacker can run code in the server process, they can `execve` anything they want, subject to permissions.

Comment: Without chroot, the security measures you describe aren't enough to prevent an attacker who compromises the minecraft account from reading all publicly-readable files on the machine, which is likely to include files that are meant to be private.

Comment: which is precisely why i mentioned that fact and said "make sure your files don't have such lax permissions"

Comment: and yes, this is far from comprehensive or perfectly secure - nothing's perfectly secure.  It is, however, adequate for the task and reasonably easy to set up.  It's essentially the standard advice for all services (like httpd, ftpd, dns, smtp, etc) - run it with its own UID and GID.

Comment: Docker offers no security by default. You need to enable user namespaces (and then nothing works because everyone uses it in insecure way).